# how to identify duplicate keys in MultiValueMap

Tags: java, data-structures, apache-commons

I have created a MultiValueMap and it has duplicate keys. I want to know how to get the list of duplicate keys and their values?

```
 key     value
  A        4
  A        6
  B        7
  C        1
```

Comment: MultiValueMap doesn't have duplicate keys as such, it has multiple values for the same key. i.e. all the keys which are equals() will be the same object. Values which are equals() don't have to be the same object.  You could get the values for each key and find which ones return more than one value.

Comment: If you were using Guava's `Multimap`, `Multimap.entries()` returns a `Collection<Map.Entry<K, V>>`.

Answer (score 2):

[MultiValueMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/map/MultiValueMap.html) doesn't allow duplicate keys. See below example.`A MultiValueMap decorates another map, allowing it to have more than one value for a key`.

```
 MultiValueMap lmap=new MultiValueMap();
    lmap.put("A", 4);
    lmap.put("A", 6);
    lmap.put("B", 7);
    lmap.put("C", 1);

    System.out.println("Size-->"+lmap.size());
```

**Which results :**

```
Size-->3
```

Answer (score 0):

`MultiValueMap` Putting a value into the map will add the value to a Collection at that key. Getting a value will return a Collection, holding all the values put to that key.

```
getCollection(key) will return Collection of values
```